# Tracking GKE POD network in-out bytes from-to regions and availability zones

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking for a utility to track and count bytes in and out for PODS to do proper billing for clients.

The node level information is not granular enough since nodes(VMs) can have multiple pods and multiple clients since everything is distributed.

Kube metrics is not enough. It only contains possible bytes, but not where the bytes came from.

I need to know if the IP that was the source of the traffic or the destination is in the same AZ or region, at least as the POD itself to not bill our network data.

Does anyone know of any such utility or possibility in GCP or a SideCar or something that could do this?

If I could get that an IP is a part of what region like AWS' public list of IPs, that would be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, you can use the `"pod/network/received_bytes_count"` and `"pod/network/sent_bytes_count"` metrics within Stackdriver Monitoring to keep track of the sent and received bytes to and from pods. [metrics_kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes)

Other than that, I would suggest you to look for another sidecar that may be more useful to you. From searching externally, there are a few tools out there that you can run to monitor network traffic on a pod level.

You can also open a GCP future request on [GCP future request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)